# Tomcat 7 not producing log output to catalina.out on RHEL7

Tags: rhel, rsyslog, tomcat, systemd-journald

I have a RHEL7 server with Apache Tomcat 7.0 installed and after a recent update to RHEL7.1 all of the logging to ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out was stopped. However I am receiving the logs inside journalctl.

If I type journalctl -u tomcat I do get the logging. Is there any way for me to get the logging also to catalina.out?

```
cat /usr/share/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
no output

journalctl -u tomcat

Aug 20 10:07:14 server.example.com server[26435]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
Aug 20 10:07:14 server.example.com server[26435]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
Aug 20 10:07:14 server.example.com server[26435]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
Aug 20 10:07:14 server.example.com server[26435]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
Aug 20 10:07:14 server.example.com server[26435]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
Aug 20 10:07:14 server.example.com server[26435]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
Aug 20 10:07:14 server.example.com server[26435]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
...
```

Comment: Have you verified that the variable "catalina.base" is set correctly?

Comment: Yes the catalina.base is set correctly.

`jinfo -sysprops 26435 | grep catalina.base
catalina.base = /usr/share/tomcat`

Comment: You could try to see of the file is opened at all by the tomcat process. Try to `stat /usr/share/tomcat/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: No, that tomcat process is not using the catalina.out file.

`stat /usr/share/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
  File: ‘/usr/share/tomcat/logs/catalina.out’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 1013845     Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: (   91/  tomcat)   Gid: (   91/  tomcat)
Access: 2015-08-19 11:21:32.835211998 +0000
Modify: 2015-08-17 03:40:02.785809293 +0000
Change: 2015-08-17 03:40:02.785809293 +0000
 Birth: -`

Comment: Ok, try to add the absolute path in the tomcat conf file and restart the service. Then retry the stat commands to see the results.

Answer (score 11):

Jamie's answer is correct that you can force rsyslog to log what's going on with tomcat. However, that doesn't answer *why* tomcat 7 on rhel 7 does not log to catalina.out. Or if it does, why does it log to both catalina.out and a catalina with a date (if you are not using an RPM install).

First, in the past around 7.0.42, Red Hat's scripts used catalina.out because their scripts were mimicking behavior of RHEL 6. As far as I'm aware, they were using "forking" for the service for `systemd`. When 7.0.56 was released, they changed that entirely by making new scripts and wrappers in /usr/libexec/tomcat to force tomcat to run in `simple` mode instead of `forked`, allowing systemd to have control of the PID and `stdout` and `stderr` to go to the journal. There is still a `catalina.$DATE.log` file in `/var/log/tomcat`, but the information is more limited from a normal `catalina.out`.

Second, let's look at /etc/tomcat/logging.properties. You'll see it sorts out the logs in a specific way between catalina, localhost, manager, host-manager. You'll also notice that it has rsyslog facility support too, and basically how it "deals" with it. What it comes down to is the `ConsoleHandler` in that file. Changing those would change the behavior of the logs in `/var/log/tomcat`.

`journalctl -u tomcat` will show you everything that catalina.out is supposed to have. As far as I'm aware, without modifying Red Hat's wrappers in /usr/libexec/tomcat, there isn't a sure fire way to make everything go to just catalina.out. If you do modify those scripts and an update comes out, your changes will be overwritten.

If you want catalina.out for sure, go with Jamie's rsyslog example configuration. Just know that it will not only fill that, but the systemd journal will also have the same information.

Comment: Good answer! It has me thinking about making incompatible changes between Tomcat releases... :|

Answer (score 6):

Creating a new file `/etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat.conf` containing the next two lines did the trick for me:

```
programname,contains,"server" /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out
programname,contains,"server" ~
```

Afterwards restart your rsyslog daemon:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the rsyslog syntax changed with the newer versions. Running 8.24.0 on RHEL 7.4, the following syntax in `/etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat.conf` got it to work for me:

```
if ($programname contains "server") then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out" flushOnTXEnd="off")
    stop
}
```

Then, as Jaimie points out restart of rsyslog was needed:

```
service rsyslog restart
```